# Connecting AVRISP MKII programmer

Tags: microcontroller, avr

I need to connect an AVRISP MkII microcontroller programmer to my ATTiny2313 microcontroller in order to program it. I've never done this before and don't want to damage the programmer,  so I have a question on the power supply connection. On [this page](http://www.atmel.com/webdoc/avrispmkii/avrispmkii.intro_connecting.html) it states that

> The AVRISP mkII does not provide power on the Vcc pin, but uses this pin to sense the voltage on the target circuitry. Your circuit needs to be powered by external means to operate.

Does this indicate that I have to connect the microcontroller's Vcc pin to 5V and then connect the programmer's Vcc pin to the same microcontroller pin? Also, does the power supply have to be exactly 5V?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does this indicate that I have to connect the microcontroller's Vcc pin to 5V and then connect the programmer's Vcc pin to the same microcontroller pin?

Yes.

> Also, does the power supply have to be exactly 5V?

No, based on its documentation [here](http://www.atmel.com/webdoc/avrispmkii/pr01.html), AVRISP MkII supports target voltages from 1.6V to 5.5V.